# C++ templates and structs problem

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have this...

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class A {
public:
    //...
private:
    struct MyStruct{
        Key key;
        Value value;
    };
};
```

And it gives me the following errors:

```
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'value' 
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
```

Some specs:
Using Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7 x64

Can my error be before or after these lines?

Comment: Show the code that's causing the error, too. By the way, you're missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: It will depend on what the type is you're sending to the template.  Can you provide an example of the full error and also an example of your usage?

Comment: that compiles for me using xcode (gcc4.2)

Comment: Are you, perchance, using an old compiler that either doesn't support templates or doesn't quite get them right?  VC++6 perhaps?

Comment: I am new to c++ so i dont really know which compiler Visual Studio c++ uses, but i doubt it doesnt support templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon after the class definition, at the very end of your code.

In some cases you need to write `typename Key key;` instead of a simple `Key key;` in templates, since the compiler may not know that `Key` is really a typename. So try this:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class A {
public:
    //...
private:
    struct MyStruct {
        /* typename not allowed here */ Key key;
        /* typename not allowed here */ Value value;
    };
};
```

Comment: @Javier: Then it should be fine.  The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Seems like i had a typo... Used T instead of Value.
But now i have another error. It says:

Error 4 error C2233: 'Table2' : arrays of objects containing zero-size arrays are illegal

Comment: This code is not valid - `typename` must go before a dependent type name (i.e. something like `Key::some_type` that depends on a template parameter), but must not go before a non-dependent type name. It wouldn't surprise me if Visual C++ accepted it here, but other compilers will reject it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the last semi-colon to end your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

First, maybe it's just a typo in the code you pasted, but you are missing the ; at the end of the class definition.

Beyond that, I don't see a problem. Make sure you are declaring an object as
`A<type, type> a;`

What are you using for your template types?

Comment: Based on what I'm reading here, it seems like your error is somewhere else and is most likely a missing semi-colon ";"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed a semi-colon to close out your class.

This compiles fine for me using g++ 4.6.1:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Key, typename Value>
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
  private:
    struct MyStruct {
        Key key;
        Value value;
    };
};

int main(void) {
    A<int, char> a;
}
```

Comment: It also compiles for me, i guess my error is somewhere else, but i cant find it!!!